# How can i use or convert fgetc() function from C in Python 3?

Tags: c, python-3.x, fgetc

I want to use fgetc() function from C in Python 3. I think i have to use: 
`ord( fp.read( 1 ) )` but i am not sure. More specific i want to convert the following code from C to Python3:

```
for(i=0;i<xdimension;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<ydimension;j++)
    {
        temp=1.164 * (fgetc(fp) - 16);
        if (temp>255) { temp=255 ; } 
        if(i>=N || j>=M) { printf("i=%d,j=%d\n",i,j);}
        framed[i*M+j]=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: All fgetc() does is read a byte of data, you can use read(0, buf, 1) and then use buf[0] or whatever version of read python uses.

Comment: post the declarations of `temp` and `framed[]`.